# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers

gcc 4.4.4 c89

Not sure why I am getting this error.

In my header file I have the following

handle.h

```
typedef struct Handle_t Handle
```

In my implementation file

handle.c

```
struct Handle {
    size_t id;
    char *name;
};

Handle* create_handle(size_t id)
{
    Handle *hdev = NULL;
    hdev = malloc(sizeof(*hdev)); /* Error */
    .
    .
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: I don't think this is why you are getting the error, but you want to use sizeof(Handle), not sizeof(*hdev).  Dereferencing hdev is dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: @Merlyn: `sizeof *hdev` is correct (as is `sizeof(Handle)`). The `sizeof` operator does not evaluate the argument, so being NULL is immaterial.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Quite the opposite. You want to use specifically `sizeof *hdev`, not `sizeof(Handle)`. The results will be the same in both cases, but `sizeof *hdev` is a better programming practice since it makes the code more type-independent. And, of course, there's no null pointer problem there, since `sizeof` does not evaluate this argument.

Comment: @pmg, AndreyT: I guess you guys are right.  Since it isn't accessing any members, it doesn't actually do anything w/ the memory/dereference.  It would also be useful in the same sort of way as C++0x `decltype`, avoiding code duplication.

Comment: @AndreyT. What do you mean when sizeof does not evaluate this argument? Thanks.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: The `sizeof` would be perfectly OK even if it accessed members. For example, `sizeof hdev->member` is fine even if `hdev` is null. `sizeof` is a *compile-time* construct. It evaluates to the *compile-time* constant - size of the *type* of its argument expression. It doesn't care about the actual *value* of the argument. Which is why it doesn't matter whether `hdev` is null, or garbage, or anything else. (The only exception from this is VLA in C99, but that does not apply here).

Comment: @AndreyT: Good information.  TY :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used to get the `typedef` wrong often until I started to think of it like two parts: **type** and **def**. The **type** first, then the **def**inition of a new name.

```
typedef <type> <name>;
typedef struct Handle Handle_t; /* defines Handle_t as struct Handle */
typedef char *c_string;         /* defines c_string as char * */
```

Comment: Just one confusing thing about typedefing. typedef struct Handle Handle_t. The 'struct Handle' part is the type. And the Handle_t is the definition. So the struct is actually called Handle_t. Would that be correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your struct's name needs to match the typedef:

```
struct Handle_t {
    /* ... */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct Handle_t Handle
```

The struct you defined is called `Handle`, not `Handle_t`, which is what you're typedeffing.

Answer (score 1):

typedef struct Handle_t Handle

you type defined struct Handle_t to Handle, but the structure is Struct Handle,so either change struct Hadle to Struct handle_t or type def.

Answer (score 1):

`struct Handle_t` is not defined by the time the compiler reaches the line with the error.

you have defined a `struct Handle` and aliased the type `Handle` to the inexistent type `struct Handle_t`. It's ok to have inexistent types for lots of things in `C`, but not for a `sizeof` argument.